# Backbone.js fetch goes to error when loading json file

Tags: android, ios, json, cordova, backbone.js

I'm trying to load a `json` from a file called internationalization.js, this is the content of the file:

```
{
    "response": {
        "loading": "Loading",
        "login.login": "Log in"
    }
}
```

This works fine on the browser, but then when building an iOS or Android App using `cordova` then the fetching fails and it goes to the `error` function. I'm wondering if the asynchronous nature of `fetch` works in a different way when on a mobile app. The file is found correctly as `xhr` holds the `json` content in the responseText, I have seen this when debugging in Safari. This is the code that does the fetching:

```
var internationalizationModel = new Model({}, {url: Config.internationalization});
internationalizationModel.fetch({
      success: _.bind(function(model){
          window.polyglot = new Polyglot({phrases: model.toJSON()});
          app.router.navigate("home",true);
      }, this),
      error: _.bind(function(model, xhr, options){
          this.logout();
      }, this)
```

Relevant methods in model:

```
      sync: function(method, model, options) {
        var urlError = function() {
            throw new Error('A "url" property or function must be specified');
        };
        if (!options.url) {
            options.url = _.result(model, 'url') || urlError();
        }
        var params = {};
        switch (method) {
            case "create":
                params = this._create(model, options);
                break;
            case "read":
                params = this._read(model, options);
                break;
            case "update":
                params = this._update(model, options);
                break;
            case "delete":
                params = this._delete(model, options);
                break;
        }
        return params;
    }
    _read: function(model, options) {
        var params = _.extend({
            headers: {Accept: "*/*; charset=utf-8","Content-Type":"application/json"},
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            url: (options.params != undefined) ? options.url + options.params : options.url,
            processData: false,
            crossDomain: true
        }, options);

        return $.ajax(params);

    }
    parse: function(res) {

        if (res.response === undefined)
            return res;

        return res.response;
    }
```

Comment: Is `internationalization.js` in the bundled app? Or is it on your server?

Comment: It's in the bundled app